# Create 3 different buttons with each click displays new image

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a javascript that will display 3 buttons and with each button it will display a different image based on that button.  Below is what I have so far.  The problem is I only show 3 buttons but no action happens when I click the button to show the image.  Thanks for help in advance.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function pic1()
    {
        document.getElementById("png").src = "C:\Users\aj\Desktop\Red Light.png";
    }
    function pic2()
    {
        document.getElementById("png").src ="C:\Users\aj\Desktop\Green Light.png";
    } 
function pic3()
    {
        document.getElementById("png").src = "C:\Users\aj\Desktop\Yellow Light.png";
    }</script>

<img src = "" id = "png "/> <input type="button" value= "Red Light" onclick="pic1()"/> 
<input type="button" value="Green Light" onclick="pic2()"/> <input type="button" value="Yellow Light" onclick="pic3()"/>
```

Comment: Your ID contains space, and that is not valid. Also URL to image should be HTTP resource and not server path.

Comment: remove the space after `png ` to `png` of id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this way after removing the **extra space** from your `<img src="" id="png" />` value ie. `png` to `png` otherwise it will cause `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

Also you can remove multiple functions to one like **pic1(),pic2(),pic3()** to **pic(this)** and based on the value of the button set the image `src` as you wish(I've used some online demo image for this example). Hope it helps :)

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pic(param) {
    if (param.value === 'Red Light') {
      document.getElementById("png").src = "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music71/v4/0f/79/15/0f79154d-fe37-001c-be03-51a29d458f22/source/1200x630bb.jpg";
      
    } else if (param.value === 'Green Light') {
      document.getElementById("png").src = "https://socialcare.blog.gov.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2013/12/green-traffic-light-md.png";
      
    } else if (param.value === 'Yellow Light')  {
      document.getElementById("png").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/1/7/4/11949849782053089133traffic_light_yellow_dan_01.svg.med.png";
    }
    //console.log(param.value)

  }
</script>

<img src="" id="png" style="width:30px; height:30px;" />
<input type="button" value="Red Light" onclick="pic(this)" />
<input type="button" value="Green Light" onclick="pic(this)" />
<input type="button" value="Yellow Light" onclick="pic(this)" />
```